# How do I detect a finger moves into or moves out of a widget

Tags: flutter

I wonder what's the best way to detect if a finger moves into or moves out of a widget, without lifting the finger?

By that I mean, for example, if I have a bunch of containers lives inside a parent container, after touching down, without lifting the finger, I move across the screen, and get notified about the containers my finger leaves and enters.

I think it should be done by adding a Listener to the parent container and listen for onPointerMove event, find a container that contains the finger position. But I have no idea how to compare finger position with container position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of thing you are asking for can be done using [RenderBox](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderBox-class.html) and [GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html).

I've prepared a demo for you so you can refer it on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/user37112898/3e9f4223520a339ac75706a06526507a).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention without lifting the finger. Simply attaching a GD doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @hgl I've updated my answer so please take a look. I've added the code to gist because it is a bit long. I recommend you to run that demo on your device and if you still have any doubt then feel free to ask.

Comment: I have this same question. Unfortunately, the gist link is no longer working.

Comment: @jason I have updated the link for the gist. I hope it helps!